# Rails Active Record: Multiple users to CRUD a post created by a different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have two models named User and Post

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

As of now, a user can create, update, delete a particular post.

I'm trying to learn Active Record deeply and I want a single post to be accessed by multiple users, if the creator of the post wants to share the post with many users.

So I was planning to add columns named *admin* and *moderator* in **Post** model, admin will hold the id of the user who had created the post and moderator will have comma separated ids of the users with whom the post is shared.

**Is it possible to achieve this through Active Record Association, if possible which association can I use?**

I am trying to understand Active Record Associations with real life examples because in the docs it's not very clear.

I'm new to Rails and I'm using Rails 5.

Comment: The given answer is perfect, though there is a special case: if you want the posts public but only editable (destroyable,...) by the owner, you can only check if current post owner is the same as the logged in owner. You don't need any extra model.

Answer (score 2):

> admin will hold the id of the user who had created the post and moderator will have comma separated ids of the users with whom the post is shared.

This is the wrong way to implement this. **Any time** you decide to store a comma-separated list of *anything* in an SQL column, you're probably designing your database incorrectly.

> Is it possible to achieve this through Active Record Association, if 
>   possible which association can I use?

Yes, this is an extremely typical usecase for ActiveRecord. You need a many-to-many association, which is easily achieved through either `has_many :through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many`.  In this case, `has_many :through` would be the best choice, as you can add additional attributes to the relationship (e.g. "moderator" or "admin" rights).

Your users should be joined to posts through something like a `PostPermissions` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_permissions
  has_many :posts, through: :post_permissions
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_permissions
  has_many :users, through: :post_permissions
end

class PostPermission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  # Permissions can be stored in any number of ways,
  # an `enum` is one simple approach
  enum permission: { :moderator, :admin }
end
```

For further details, check out the [has_many :through section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) of the ActiveRecord Association guide.